# Will a digital potentiometer work with 230 volts (ac)?

Tags: potentiometer

Will a digital potentiometer work in a circuit that uses UK mains power (230vac)?
I want to be able to adjust the voltage digitally.

How could I digitally (or non-manually) control the voltage of a 230vac circuit?

Comment: The datasheet should tell you the answer. Without part numbers, it's impossible to say for certain. Edit: Also, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @exscape I don't have any datasheets because I thought there might be some sort of peak value that potentiometers wont operate at.

Comment: @exscape I'm trying to control the voltage in a circuit where the power source is the mains supply (UK). I need to be able to control the voltage, digitally, so that the voltage can range from 1-230vac

Comment: Asking a question on a public forum, then being all mysterious and secretive when asked about the objective, is a very endearing attitude.

Comment: How is this not directly and clearly answered in the datasheet? -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess no digital potentiometer will allow you to do what you want. They are tipically used to drive low-voltage electronic circuits. You probably need an adjustable transformer (varivolt) or some kind of switching AC-AC converter to achieve what you want.

Comment: hmm... damn. Well I'm sure there are plenty of alternative ways to solve this anyway. Thanks.

Comment: For sure the digital potentiometer might be used to adjust the power electronics used on the AC-AC converter, but making this converter is not easy if you never did it before. What exactly is your need for this 1-230VAC output? Clarifying that might help so we can propose realistic solutions.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea and now I think I have the solution :D Thanks again.

Comment: Can you share it with us? If you think my answer was enough to get you to the solution I'd be glad if you could check it as "accepted" :)

Comment: This question is to do with my project. I might make an account here later next year when I'm finished and explain to everyone what I was doing and how I did it but for now my project is going to stay unknown. But when it's finished it should be awesome :D

Comment: @Anonymous I hope you are done with publishing your project. Can you share the solution now.. I am facing the similar problem, i have to dim a light based on certain paramters...seems like i have same problem statement.